# Exporting metrics from multiple spark exeutors running on single node using prometheus JMX agent

Tags: apache-spark, jmx, prometheus

I am running spark cluster and I have one node which has three executors running on it. I want to scrap metrics for all three executors using Prometheus JMX agent. I am passing Prometheus java agent using "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions" in spark submit command like below.

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:/opt/agent/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=6677:/opt/agent/spark.yml"
```

I am passing port as 6677 and JMX metrics are available for one executor only. For other two executors javaagent will fail as port 6677 is already in use and there will be no metrics reported for other two executors. Can someone please guide me how to solve this problem. I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574377/exporting-spark-worker-executor-metrics-to-prometheus-using-jmxagent) but there is no answer for that.

Comment: @brian-brazil Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use different ports for the other 2 executors? You can't have 3 servers listening on the same port and this has nothing to do with Prometheus or JMX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Spark will launch three executors on single machine and all the executors will get same Prometheus jar file, yml file and port number through spark.executor.extraJavaOptions.

Comment: run executors exposing metrics to different ports.  configure prometheus with three jobs to scrape metrics from all 3 ports.  I don't think there's a way to specify port range in prometheus config.

Comment: hi @sevenfourk can you please show an example for this ?